# Add New Keyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I am Trying to add New Keyboard in my app but I am unable Get any Solutions,Normally we can add new keyboard from General > Keyboards.
But is there any possible way through we which we can add directly through code.

Any help will be appreciable.
Thank You

This is what I tried to change the language.

```
- (UITextInputMode *)textInputMode {
    for (UITextInputMode *inputMode in [UITextInputMode activeInputModes]) {
        if ([[self langFromLocale:[self localeKey]] isEqualToString:[self langFromLocale:inputMode.primaryLanguage]]) {
            return inputMode;
        }
    }

    return [super textInputMode];
}


- (NSString*)localeKey {
    NSArray* lang = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSString* currentLang = lang[0];

    return currentLang;
}

- (NSString *)langFromLocale:(NSString *)locale {
    NSRange r = [locale rangeOfString:@"_"];
    if (r.length == 0) r.location = locale.length;

    NSRange r2 = [locale rangeOfString:@"-"];
    if (r2.length == 0) r2.location = locale.length;

    return [[locale substringToIndex:MIN(r.location, r2.location)] lowercaseString];
}
```

I can only change the language when the keyboards of that language is added from settings else I can't hence I am looking to add new keyboards.

Comment: do you add custom keyboard???

Comment: No, I have default keyboard

Comment: I am looking for something similar, let me know if you have found something.